# How to replicate what Excel does to plot a "Scatter with smooth lines" graph

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

I need to replicate an Excel "Scatter with Smooth Lines" graph in code. I'm trying to use a line with Highcharts, so I'm must get the data that Excel uses to build the smooth line.

**This is Excel:** (note that the highest point is not a point in the series)
[image]

And I got this using a `Spline` (Not the same thing, I know) http://jsfiddle.net/qF6Va/1/

[image]

**What algorithm should I use to get the smooth excel line data?**

Comment: Your title and body text seem to say the opposite things... Are you trying to replicate what Excel does into Highcharts, or trying to replicate what highcharts does into Excel?

Comment: Trying to replicate what excel does.

Comment: @Duniyadnd: it's better now?

Comment: Yes - trying to solve it now... :)

Comment: It looks like that this may be how Highcharts handles spline charts - there is nothing in their documentation on how you can handle the elasticity of the spline graph... the only other suggestion I can give is provide an additional point to push the line a little higher

Comment: @Duniyadnd: Yes!, that's what I'm trying to do (sorry for not being clear). But, how? How to get the data points to build the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using a `Cubic Spline` with the help of this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12018/Interpolation-with-Polynomials-and-Splines)

[image]